# Starting MySQL in non-administrator environment on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to start MySQL in my company environment. I do have permissions to run any type of file, but I do not have administrator access. I found on StackOverflow that it is possible to run mysql as non administrator by running mysqld directly. However, when I do I get the following error:

```
H:\Programs\mysql>bin\mysqld --console --log_syslog=0
2017-09-11T11:10:06.059072Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is
 deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see doc
umentation for more details).
2017-09-11T11:10:06.059072Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operatio
ns related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-09-11T11:10:06.074672Z 0 [Note] bin\mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19) starting as proc
ess 504 ...
2017-09-11T11:10:06.402278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows in
terlocked functions
2017-09-11T11:10:06.402278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-11T11:10:06.402278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are u
sed for memory barrier
2017-09-11T11:10:06.402278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-09-11T11:10:06.464679Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-11T11:10:06.495880Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-11T11:10:06.542681Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total siz
e = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-09-11T11:10:06.558281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer
pool
2017-09-11T11:10:06.963889Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Ba
rracuda.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.385097Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temp
orary tables
2017-09-11T11:10:07.400697Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12
MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-09-11T11:10:07.463099Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.509899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found.
96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.509899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are
 active.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.509899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-09-11T11:10:07.572301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.19 started; log sequence number
 1210037
2017-09-11T11:10:07.572301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from H:\Prog
rams\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-09-11T11:10:07.572301Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.603501Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 17
0911 13:10:07
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2017-09-11T11:10:07.603501Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please
run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.665902Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Tabl
e 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.681503Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the foll
owing SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and priva
te key
2017-09-11T11:10:07.681503Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port:
3306
2017-09-11T11:10:07.697103Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.697103Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2017-09-11T11:10:07.697103Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to create a socket for IPv4 '0.0.0.
0': errno: 0.
2017-09-11T11:10:07.697103Z 0 [ERROR] Can't create IP socket: No such file or di
rectory
2017-09-11T11:10:07.697103Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I believe this has nothing to do with me not using admin, but rather the ip not able to bind in my company environment. I cannot install MySQL via the regular way due to not having administrator rights. Also, I do not have any my.ini file to set things like this up.

Answer (score 0):

TALK with your leader/administrator of the application to get the direction necessary for you to be successful (with their awareness / permission ).

Comment: It already took more than a month to get the permission to even run .exe files, so I did not want to go down that path again. However, if there's no other solution I guess it'll do.